# NSUserDefaults Saving Score

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, hud

I am looking for some advice when it comes to saving a score in my app - I currently have a coin count working in which through my HUD class when I collide through Coins the value increases accordingly. My next step is trying to initiate a high-score that initiates, after some research I think the topic I am looking into is based around `NSUserDefaults`..

The current code :

```
   import SpriteKit

   class HUD: SKNode {


   //An SKLabelNode to print the coin score:
   let coinCountText = SKLabelNode(text: "000000")


   func createHUDNodes(){

   // Configure the coin text label:
   coinCountText.fontName = "STHupo-Heavy-Italic"
   let coinTextPosition = CGPoint(x: -cameraOrigin.x + 770, y: coinPosition.y)
   coinCountText.position = coinTextPosition

   coinCountText.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.left
   coinCountText.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentMode.center

   // Add the text label and coin icon to the HUD:
   self.addChild(coinCountText)

   }


   func setCoinCountDisplay(newCoinCount:Int) {

   let formatter = NumberFormatter()
   let number = NSNumber(value: newCoinCount)
   formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 6
   if let coinStr =
        formatter.string(from: number) {

        // Update the label node with the new count:
        coinCountText.text = coinStr
    }
}
```

Working in the HUD class I think naturally I would need to create another 'SKlabelNode'for the highscore node which I can duplicate from the code that works above.. my problem is how can I implement a highscore feature in the app, as when closed and re-opening the application it will remember the highscore..

I assume the following code would need to be added but I do not understand how it ties together in the class.

```
     var currentHighScore =  
     NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("coin_highscore")

     var highScoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"STHupo-Heavy-Italic")
     highScoreLabel.text = ""
     highScoreLabel.fontSize = 45
     highScoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: viewSize.width * 0.5, y: viewSize.height * 0.30)
     self.addChild(highScoreLabel)

     if (score > currentHighScore) {

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(score, forKey: "player_highscore")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

        highScoreLabel.text = "New High Score: \(score) !"


    } else {

        highScoreLabel.text = "Better Luck Next Time: \(score)"
    }
}
```

Any advice on how I could integrate this code would be much appreciated.

,  AJ

---

Revised :

```
     else if nodeTouched.name == "returnToMenu"{
     // Transition to the main menu scene
     self.view?.presentScene(MenuScene(size: self.size),transition.crossFade(withDuration: 0.6))

     let currentHighScore = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Player_highscore")

     let highScoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"STHupo-Heavy-Italic")
     highScoreLabel.text = "Value: \ (String(describing: coin.value))"
     highScoreLabel.text = ""
     highScoreLabel.fontSize = 45
     highScoreLabel.zPosition = 100
     highScoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)

     self.addChild(highScoreLabel)

     if (coin.value > currentHighScore) {

     UserDefaults.standard.set(coin.value, forKey: "Player_highscore")

     UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

     highScoreLabel.text = "New High Value: \(String(describing: coin.value)) !"


     } else {

     highScoreLabel.text = "Better Luck Next Time: \(String(describing: coin.value))"

                            }
                    }
            }

}
```

I am assuming it's the referencing to my original HUD that is causing the problem? In my coin class I declared the coin.value = 5, each time the coin is collected by coinCountDisplay increases accordingly. However still does not show - :/

Comment: Don't use `"New High Value: \(String(describing: coin.value)) !"`, use `"New High Value: \(coin.value) !"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Add a property to your view controller with both get and set and use it in all the places. The get method should get the value from `UserDefaults` and the set should update the value in `UserDefaults`.

```swift
var coinHighscore: Int {
    get {
        UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "coin_highscore")
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "coin_highscore")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending on Frankenstein's answer, IF you want to use **Swift 5** you can use `Property Wrappers` to avoid writing `get` and `set` every time:

```
@propertyWrapper struct UserDefaultsBacked<Value> {
    let key: String
    let defaultValue: Value
    var storage: UserDefaults = .standard

    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get {
            let value = storage.value(forKey: key) as? Value
            return value ?? defaultValue
        }
        set {
            storage.setValue(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
@UserDefaultsBacked(key: "coin_highscore", defaultValue: 0)
var coinHighscore: Int
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the comments - didn't anticipate for such a quick response! I had been looking at trying the follow at the bottom of my GameScene which doesn't error however I can't see the SKLabelNode appear? : Code revised to follow :

Comment: Does the `highScoreLabel` appear on the screen but with the wrong value or is it just not showing?

Comment: Hello, I've just revised my code in the original post - it's not showing at all... :/

Comment: This means the problem is with your `highScoreLabel` and not with `UserDefaults`.

Comment: I will amend this first and get back - think I might be able to overcome this as a starting point! Thanks to all for the support so far! :)

Comment: Hello - Right, I've revised this within my GameOver function in which the SKLabelNode appears fine. :) I adjusted the the      highScoreLabel.text = "000000"    It does not however update a score duirng gameplay. I am wondering if it's not picking up the coin value.. Within the coin class I have set the      var = 5          I don't suppose you would be able to direct me to any resources you may have come across on this topic? :) Thanks again!

Comment: You can try some debug printing to see what are the exact values of your variables (`currentHighScore`, `coin.value`...). But this question was about `UserDefaults`(hope we answered your issues). Please create another question if you have problems with displaying the coin value - I'll be happy to help you there.